# How to use gdb to find a floating point exception in g++ code

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb, g++

I have a g++ program that runs without user input.  Somewhere the program is interrupted and it says "Floating point exception." Can gdb help me find what's causing this in my code? How?

Comment: What happens when you run it in GDB?

Comment: I get 
Program received signal SIGFPE, Arithmetic exception.
0x0000000000403519 in main ()

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can get help on [GDB here](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/GDB-Commands.html) and  [at Gnu's site here](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Using-gdb.html).

But the basics are this:

```
$ gdb ./your_program             // start gdb on the program
> run                            // run the program
> run argv1 argv2                // or run it with command line arguments
(floating point exception)       // let it run until exception occurs
> bt                             // bt will show the stack trace
```

Here are some gdb settings on how to make sure it stops on [floating point exceptions](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Handling-floating-point-exceptions.html).

Comment: When I run bt I ge #0  0x0000000000403519 in main ().  But I can't figure out what to do with that.

Comment: Did you build with the -g option to include debugging symbols?

Comment: When I do that, I get Program received signal SIGFPE, Arithmetic exception.
0x0000000000403519 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe448) at btree.cpp:1310.  Then when I run bt I get 
#0  0x0000000000403519 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe448) at btree.cpp:1310

1310     total = (end-start)/(frequency/1000); So now I can see what line in the program is causing it, but I'm still not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Likely, frequency is 0 or very close to it, though there may be other reasons.  I can't fix it either without seeing your code.  What does gdb show when you print frequency?

Comment: Is `frequency` a float?  Note that c uses integer division (by default), so if frequency is an integer less than 1000, `frequency/1000` will always be `0`.  Divide by zero is usually an FPE.

Comment: frequency is an int. 
When I print frequency I get 
$1 = 0

Comment: change it to `((frequency+0.000001)/1000.0)` to avoid dividing by zero.  Or you may have a prettier approach, hard to tell without the code.

Comment: I just set frequency = 1000 right after it is declared and that fixed the problem.  The function that was supposed to set the value of frequency was commented out so frequency was just 0 before.

Comment: @Whirlwind: heh, True, except that he said it's an integer.